# Alt -Tab - Changing the location of window name from the middle area to just below the Window image

Tags: 20.04, gnome

How can I change the location of the window name presented in the middle section of the Alt-Tab box to just below the window itself?

[image]

The problem I'm facing is that there are multiple windows for the same application and to find the correct one I've to press `Tab` and then look at the name shown in the middle. This does not seem to be a good experience as I've to change the focus area multiple times. If the name is shown just below the selected window then I will not have to look at other locations to find the name.

1. OS: Ubuntu 20.04
2. GNOME Version: 3.36.8
3. Windowing System: X11

Comment: You would need a GNOME extension to do this and i don't think someone had the idea to make this extension. You can still check at https://extensions.gnome.org/

Comment: Please, share your experience if you find something useful.

Comment: Hi @FedonKadifeli, I've asked this question on Gnome discourse as well. Here's the link: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/alt-tab-changing-the-location-of-window-name-from-the-middle-area-to-just-below-the-window-image/6662.